# C++ cout hex format

Tags: c++

i am a c coder, new to c++.

i try to print the following with cout with strange output. Any comment on this behaviour is appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        unsigned char x = 0xff;

        cout << "Value of x  " << hex<<x<<"  hexadecimal"<<endl;

        printf(" Value of x %x by printf", x);
}
```

output:

```
 Value of x  ÿ  hexadecimal
 Value of x ff by printf
```

Answer (score 28):

`<<` handles `char` as a 'character' that you want to output, and just outputs that byte exactly. The `hex` only applies to integer-like types, so the following will do what you expect:

```
cout << "Value of x  " << hex << int(x) << "  hexadecimal" << endl;
```

Billy ONeal's suggestion of `static_cast` would look like this:

```
cout << "Value of x  " << hex << static_cast<int>(x) << "  hexadecimal" << endl;
```

Comment: so the "<<hex " is not equivalent to printf ("%x", x), where, the bit stream at that location is treated as a hex value ?

Thanks a lot for the responses..it is very helpful

Comment: @pdk: It is meant to be the equivalent, but it only has an effect when `cout << x` would normally output some decimal representation. Since `cout << (a char)` doesn't (it outputs that byte directly), the `hex` makes no sense, and is not applied. Thus, we force a conversion to an `int` type, and the `<<` that deals with `int` is called, which outputs a hex representation.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the comments, were really helpful.
So to summarise, as far as i understood, the unsigned char overload happens in this case. And << hex is ignored, resulting output in char format.

Answer (score 5):

You are doing the hex part correctly, but x is a character, and C++ is trying to print it as a character. You have to cast it to an integer.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        unsigned char x = 0xff;

        cout << "Value of x  " << hex<<static_cast<int>(x)<<"  hexadecimal"<<endl;

        printf(" Value of x %x by printf", x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Starkey.

Then why printf , prints the hex value of the character correctly ? I am sorry for this basic q ...

Comment: In printf by specifying %x you are telling C++ how to interpret x, whereas with hex << x the compiler will use the unsigned char overload of the streaming operator since this is the type. By changing the type of x to int, the int overload of << will apply.

Comment: @cletus: C++ has printf, too.  That being said, the two functions have completely different strategies.  I find `cout` more intuitive for everyday use, but it tends to become painful compared to `printf` once you want fancy formatting of output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should expect to know how to convert `hex` to `dec` since you have already assigned `unsigned char x = 0xff;`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    unsigned char x = 0xff;
    std::cout << std::dec << static_cast<int>(x) << std::endl;
}
```

which shall give the value `255` instead.

Further detail related to the the `str` stream to `dec` shall refer in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/dec/.

If you want to know the hexadecimal value from the decimal one, here is a simple example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    int x = 255;

    std::cout << std::showbase << std::setw(4) << std::hex << x << std::endl;
}
```

which prints `oxff`.

The library `<iomanip>` is optional if you want to see `0x` ahead of `ff`. The original reply related to `hex` number printing was in http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/51591/.